# PHP headers not working before a location header

Tags: php, header

On my web application, I want the user to download some information on a page and redirect after the same.

```
<?php 
 header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: text/force-donwload');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=Your_Fibble_Password.txt');
    header('Content-Length: '.strlen($password));
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    echo $password;
    header('location:./');
 ?>
```

So Here the location header works and the page is been redirected
 but the headers for the file transfer above aren't working.
**Note: I can't use exit as I got some code executing below it.**

Comment: `header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');` try that replacing yours, which has a typo anyway and you should not try to run code after redirecting the user

Comment: @smith i'm running the code before the header

Comment: @smith and It's not working either

Comment: ok looking at this again, you cant do a file download AND a redirect (header location) its one or the other

Comment: @smith okay got it. any idea to do what I want to do with the location header?

Comment: serve the file on the page redirected to.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, it's not possible do this. The technical limitation is: "You can't send headers after the content", so, in this case, you are sending the password to download (in txt format file) and then you try to send more headers to indicate a redirection.
Maybe you could simulate this behaviour from the frontend application, performing a document.location in javascript.

Comment: And would you like to tell me how to do it with js or jquey?

Comment: Sure, one stackoverflow user explained how to do it, you can take a look at http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/

Comment: i'm sorry but I am not looking for that. I actually want the user to download just a text file without storing it on the server as many users will download it with **different content**

Comment: That link is an example about how to fix the problem, you can download whatever you want dynamically without store one file in the server... example, user with id 123a asks to download his password, so, that user will invoke /download/password/123a and backend understand needs to download the password file for user 123a

Comment: I got it. Thanks for the answer and here's what I want (https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/189/how-to-create-a-file-and-generate-a-download-with-javascript-in-the-browser-without-a-server)